# How to get elements from essential List programmatically

Tags: development, list-view, data-view-web-part, view, dynamics-crm

I have gotten two lists (like a view) from Microsoft Dynamics CRM. How can I get a elements from these two lists to the C# Sharepoint code in `.cs` file. The Administrator of CRM told me that this lists are made by **Business Data Connectivity**. How can I call them from the code? How to put `CAML` Query to it?

**Edited.**

Here is my example of code:

```
            string FullQueryUrlap = "<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Geq><And><Leq><FieldRef Name='{2}' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{3}</Value></Leq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Nazwisko' /><Value Type='Note'>{4}</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Imie' /><Value Type='Note'>{5}</Value></Eq></And></And></And></Where>";
        string dateISO1 = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(1.0));
        Convert.ToDateTime(dateISO1);
        string dateISO2 = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(2.0));
        Convert.ToDateTime(dateISO2);

        int spacja = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.IndexOf(" ");

        var queryPoszczegolnyUrlop = new SPQuery();
        queryPoszczegolnyUrlop.Query = String.Format(FullQueryUrlap, "DataKon", dateISO1, "DataPoc", dateISO2, DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper().Substring(0, spacja), DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper().Substring(spacja+1));
        queryPoszczegolnyUrlop.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='DataPoc' /><FieldRef Name='DataKon' />";
        queryPoszczegolnyUrlop.ViewFieldsOnly = true;

        // Wyświetlanie poszczególnego pracownika wybranego z DropDownList1
   //      Label2.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper().Substring(0, spacja) + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper().Substring(0, spacja).Length + " | " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper().Substring(spacja+1) + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper().Substring(spacja+1).Length;

        SPListItemCollection listaDniUrlopow = witryna1.Lists["ListaUrlopow2012"].GetItems(queryPoszczegolnyUrlop);

        DateTime dataPoc= new DateTime();
        DateTime dataKon = new DateTime();

        for (int interator = 0; interator < listaDniUrlopow.Count; interator++)
        {
            SPListItem item = listaDniUrlopow[interator];
            dataPoc = Convert.ToDateTime(item["DataPoc"]);
            dataKon = Convert.ToDateTime(item["DataKon"]);
```

Hov could I get a Internal name of the Esential list in **BDC**.

Comment: Are you trying to get CRM data into SharePoint or SharePoint data into CRM?

Comment: CRM data into Sharepoint. The Administrators of CRM shared me databy Business Data Conectivity. How could I read them?

Comment: What error does the above code give? (other than the syntax for the unclosed for loop)

Comment: The Title field isn't find. But I warried that i can't find in BDC view a Esential List Internal Name

Comment: If your content type doesn't have a Title field, don't include it in the query. I have difficulty understanding the rest of what you said.

Comment: I found out the Solution :) My Admin don't change Internal Names, He Change only a Display Name, not Internal Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF they are exposed in SharePoint as an External list then you can just read them like a regular list.

Comment: Please vrite it's as a comment. I have got only a View of list. How could I call them. I updated my question.

Comment: I found out the Solution :) My Admin don't change Internal Names, He Change only a Display Name, not Internal Name

Answer (score 0):

Check my blog for read data from sharepoint list programmatically:

http://malgoul2000.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/read-data-from-sharepoint-list-programmatically/

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.