# BDC Model for ActiveDirectory

Tags: active-directory, external-content-type, bdc-model

I am trying to build a BDC Model and a custom .net connector for ActiveDirectory so that users can search for data in AD from Sharepoint as well as create lists (ie: Users list that will show users from AD) and was hoping anyone has done something similar but I can't find any material on the web. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction on how can this be acomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the Active Directory using methods in the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace in the C# methods for your BCS model, and build it up as you would any external content type. I did something similar when first starting with BCS and it's really not any different from working with any other data source.

For an example of interacting with the namespace, here are the `ReadItem` and `ReadList` methods I wrote (as I said, it was a while ago and never intended as anything more than a learning excercise):

```
public static Staff ReadItem(string id)
{
    PrincipalContext _adContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "developer");
    UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(_adContext);
    u.SamAccountName = id;

    PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(u);
    u = (UserPrincipal)search.FindOne();
    search.Dispose();

    Staff result = getUserDetail(u);

    return result;
}

public static IEnumerable<Staff> ReadList()
{
    List<Staff> result = new List<Staff>();

    PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "developer");
    UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(AD);
    PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(u);

    foreach (UserPrincipal user in search.FindAll())
    {
        Staff userdetail = getUserDetail(user);
        result.Add(userdetail);
    }

    search.Dispose();

    return result;
}
```

Here `developer` is the domain name, and getUserDetail is just a method mapping AD attributes to the properties of the `Staff` class.

However, before investing too much effort into going down this route, I'd advise that you consider importing the AD entities as User objects themselves with User Profile Synchronisation, as there are a lot of pieces of SharePoint that make things to do with "people" better-suited to a User object than an element of a list, and it's probably something you'd be doing anyway.

Comment: And how Can I get a list element in BDC ?

Comment: @GrzegorzZ I don't understand your question. The BCS methods are used by BCS whenever you query the content type. You'd typically then have an external list and query that using the object model.

Comment: I have got a List as Esential list from CRM Microsoft Dynamics, and I want to read this list. At my Sharepoint it shows me like a List View, but I don't have got a object of column. How Can I get a internal Name for each column in this View ?

Comment: @TZHX - I suppose I need to update the question but I want to build a tool that will build the model dynamically by traversing ActiveDirectory's directory entries and building entities from them which can give me not only users but also computers, groups, etc.

Comment: @TZHX You Can read my problem here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53433/how-to-get-elements-from-essential-list-programmatically

Comment: @AdamHobbs Ah, ok. No, I've never seen anything like that; and I doubt such a thing could be done efficiently; SharePoint's pickyness over it's XML being what it is. I considered building a tool to auto-generate parts of the BDCM XML & Services, but it was just far too much effort to build something that would only work with the simplest of cases.

Comment: @GrzegorzZ I see. If I felt like I could answer your question, I'd do it on that thread, not this one.

Comment: Ok. Thank You If You could read this question please.